# RavenDB and shard rebalancing

Tags: nosql, ravendb, sharding

How does RavenDB handles shard rebalancing/redistribution of data?

> var shards = new Dictionary                {
>   {"Asia", new DocumentStore {Url = "http://localhost:8080"}},
>   {"Middle East", new DocumentStore {Url = "http://localhost:8081"}},
>   {"America", new DocumentStore {Url = "http://localhost:8082"}},
>   };

For example in the above excerpt taken from their tutorial, the server containing Asia is impacted because China alone is over 1B people. So I need that data to be split between Asia1 (China) and Asia2 (The rest). What's the best way to rebalance the existing data?

Do I need to query all the Asia in the original document store and manually move them over to the new shard? Is there a faster way? Will an effort like this involve some down time? Do new indexes need to be rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

Alwyn,
Usually, what will happen is that you'll add a Asia-2 server, and change your sharding function to createa all new Asia items in the Asia-2 server.
You do that by overriding GenerateShardIdFor in the ShardResolutionStrategy.
It doesn't require downtime or any new indexes.

Comment: so what will happen to existing data? They need to be moved over to the new shard, do you just run an update to convert them accordingly?